# How do I link a static library in a cpp source file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

There's a #pragma command to link in a library from the source file rather than from the project settings. I just can't seem to remember it.

Can anyone here remind me?

Thanks

Comment: This is compiler-specific and does not work, in general, in C++.

Comment: Linking is outside the scope of a source file.  Linking usually involves combining translated source files without their knowledge.  This is commonly done in a makefile, build file or project file.

Comment: What compiler & platform?  Could be different on PC, Linux or embedded system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "library")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You mean this thing 
`#pragma comment(lib, "Library")`